# Returning array of prime factors with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, prime-factoring

Here is my code. I am trying to push my factors into an array but I'm unable to and stuck on what to do. I get the factors just fine when I console.log it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
primer = (num, factor = 2,) => {
    const factors = []
    if (num < 2) {
        return factors
    }
    if (num % factor == 0) {
        factors.push(factor)
        console.log(factor)
        primer(num / factor, factor);
    }
    else {
        primer(num, factor + 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: What makes you think you're *not* pushing `factor` to the array? You don't *return* the array, and it's local to the function, so it's not available outside the function unless you return it. And, since you're calling it recursively, you're creating a *new* array with each call, further compounding the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `factors = []` is a different array every time you recursively call the function. You need to make sure to add your recursive results to your current results:

```js
primer = (num, factor = 2) => {
    const factors = [];
    if (num < 2) {
        return factors;
    }
    if (num % factor == 0) {
        factors.push(factor);
        factors.push(...primer(num / factor, factor, factors));
    }
    else {
        factors.push(...primer(num, factor + 1, factors));
    }
    return factors; // And remember to return!
}
```

Note that we're creating a new array every time we recurse above, which isn't ideal. Another way to do this while avoiding creating new arrays would be to use an extra `factors` array param and make sure to append to it:

```js
primer = (num, factor = 2, factors = []) => {
    if (num < 2) {
        return factors;
    }
    if (num % factor == 0) {
        factors.push(factor);
        primer(num / factor, factor, factors);
    }
    else {
        primer(num, factor + 1, factors);
    }
    return factors;
}
```

Comment: ohh thank you so much! I wasn't sure where to go from where I was at, but now I understand what i was doing incorrectly